# postgresql - integer out of range

Tags: postgresql

I've set up a table accordingly:

```
CREATE TABLE raw (
    id          SERIAL,
    regtime     float NOT NULL,
    time        float NOT NULL,
    source      varchar(15),
    sourceport  INTEGER,
    destination varchar(15),
    destport    INTEGER,
    blocked     boolean
); ... + index and grants
```

I've successfully used this table for a while now, and all of a sudden the following insert doesn't work any longer..

```
INSERT INTO raw(
    time, regtime, blocked, destport, sourceport, source, destination
) VALUES (
    1403184512.2283964, 1403184662.118, False, 2, 3, '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2'
);
```

The error is: `ERROR: integer out of range`

Not even sure where to begin debugging this.. I'm not out of disk-space and the error itself is kinda discreet.

Comment: Show the whole insert command.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto that is it.. copy and pasted.. Unix timestamp is `1403184512.2283964` and `1403184662.118` respectively, both are fine and does not affect the result in any way what so ever. Also they are placed at the beginning of both the insert clumn definitions and the value definitions. So the position is not the issue here.

Comment: The INSERT did not supply values for the regtime and time fields, which both are not-NULLable. BTW `time` is a reserved word (typename) using it as an identifier is asking for trouble.

Comment: Show the whole insert command.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto again, no idea what the point of it all is but for the sake of me being in a good mood, there you go. Edit done.

Comment: Any chance that your `id` generator has passed 2^31?

Comment: Try `select max(id) from raw`. You also might try changing the type of ID from SERIAL (4 byte signed integer) to BIGSERIAL (8 byte signed integer). Share and enjoy.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on PostgreSQL 9.3. The sequence underlying the "id" column is the most likely problem. What does `select currval('raw_id_seq')` return? (The name of your sequence might be different; mine is PostgreSQL's default.)

Comment: @BobJarvis and Mike, mow that you mentioned it that *might* be it, have to confirm tomorrow or later this evening!

Comment: @NickBarnes and the rest, post that as an answer, that was the issue. used `SERIAL` instead of `BIGSERIAL`

Comment: Unrelated but: `float` is a *approximate* data type. You don't necessarily get the same value back that you specify in your `insert` statement. If you care for exact values you should use `numeric`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`SERIAL` columns are stored as `INTEGER`s, giving them a maximum value of 2<sup>31</sup>-1. So after ~2 billion inserts, your new `id` values will no longer fit.

If you expect this many inserts over the life of your table, create it with a `BIGSERIAL` (internally a `BIGINT`, with a maximum of 2<sup>63</sup>-1).

If you discover later on that a `SERIAL` isn't big enough, you can increase the size of an existing field with:

```
ALTER TABLE raw ALTER COLUMN id TYPE BIGINT;
```

Note that it's `BIGINT` here, rather than `BIGSERIAL` (as [serials aren't real types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)). And keep in mind that, if you actually have 2 billion records in your table, this might take a little while...

Comment: The syntax i used was `ALTER TABLE raw ALTER COLUMN id TYPE BIGINT` but i guess it's all the same :)

Comment: @Torxed Yeah, the `COLUMN` keyword is optional, but it does make things a little clearer. Updated ;)

Comment: The alter table is not practically doable on a live database indeed it rebuilds the table locking it for the full duration of it.

Comment: @Gaetano: True, if you caught this early then you might want something more elaborate to avoid the downtime (e.g. add a trigger-maintained duplicate of `id` and rename it once it's populated). But if every insert is already failing with an `integer out of range` error, then your system is not exactly "live", and I think you'll just need to wait it out...