# Can I change type of auto-increment id in postgresql and not broke all around?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, auto-increment, biginteger

I have a postgresql table with auto-increment id which is integer (it was created by python django). So now I reached integer max_value 2.14 billion rows.

And according to this answer ([postgresql - integer out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308239/postgresql-integer-out-of-range)) I want to change type of id column to biginteger. And my general question is - if change it it will not broke auto-increment? And shouldn't it change my data in this table? Should I create some new sequences after these changes?

This is a postgresql description for this column:

```
Column|  Type   |            Modifiers                                                     | Storage  
id    | integer | not null default nextval('parsedata_app_ticket_id_seq'::regclass)        | plain
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you just need to change the data type of the column, the sequence will generate biginteger values anyway:

```
alter table the_table
   alter id type bigint
```

Comment: As a little feedback I want to share what's happening with this case. I did it like in answer, it starts very well, BUT. Yes, unfortunally there was a but. The process starts and was going, was going without the end. And after 2 days I it wasn't finished and I think it became dead process which will never finish. So I hard-finished it, because this table was necessary. After that I rename old table and create new one this previous name. So new table was already with bigint and it start to get new data. And old table I just use as archive. RESUME - this answer is correct, but for a big data NO.

Comment: @Zext: your statement was probably waiting to acquire the lock on the table. Next time, check `pg_stat_activity` if your session is doing something or if it's waiting